# Undefined method sort for Enumerator

Tags: ruby, sorting, methods, iterator

I implemented the Greedy algorithim in ruby using the following code:

```
class Greedy
  def initialize(unit, total, *coins)
    @total_coins1 = 0
    @total_coins2 = 0
    @unit = unit
    @total = total
    @reset_total = total
    @currency = coins.map 
    @currency.sort!
    @currency = @currency.reverse
    unless @currency.include?(1)
      @currency.push(1)
    end
  end
  def sorter
    @currency.each do |x|
      @pos = @total / x
      @pos = @pos.floor
      @total_coins1 += @pos
      @total -= x * @pos
      puts "#{@pos}: #{x} #{@unit}"
    end
    puts "#{@total_coins1} total coins"
  end
end
```

When I try to run the code:

```
x = Greedy.new("cents", 130, 50, 25, 10, 5)
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sort!' for #<Enumerator: [50, 25, 10, 5]:map>
    from /Users/Solomon/Desktop/Ruby/greedy.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Being very new to Ruby, I have no idea what this means, nor how to fix it, because `[50, 25, 10, 5].sort!` is a perfectly valid method... How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here: `@currency = coins.map`

If you call `map` without a block, it will return an `Enumerator`. What is it you wanted to map here? If there's nothing you want to do with the values of `coins`, just assign `@currency = coins.sort.reverse` and save yourself the `sort!` and `reverse` steps.

Comment: I wanted to map `coins` to an array

Comment: See update. You don't have to map it to an array btw, it already is one because of your use of the splat operator (`*`) in your argument list.

Comment: That isn't really what I want, sorry, I need @currency to be sorted, and that doesn't do it.

Comment: Of course `@currency` will be sorted if you do it this way. You take the `coins` array, call `sort` on it, then `reverse` it (there's better ways to do reverse sort by the way, see `sort_by` and then assign the final result to `@currency`.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerator does not have sort method. It belongs to Enumerable. Map method without block returns an enumerator.

In your example you already use * splatten operator so coins is already an array. But if you insist to force converting it, you can use

```
@currency  = coins.to_a
@currency = @currency.sort!
```

Or just shorten to:

```
@currency = coins.to_a.sort
```

to_a method will convert it to array and equivalent to:

```
coins = coins.map{|x| x}
```